# Run javascript on button press ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, code-behind

I would like to call javascript function in case something in my code behind would happen.

If it is like the code below it works fine after postback alert windows shows and says it correctly. But in case I remove the comment from else block none of those two scripts in else block will happen?

Is there any limit on how many of these action could I make from codebehind?

```js
if (condition) {
  if (condition2) {
    var message = "It happened !";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "yep1", "alert('" + message + "')", true);
  }

} else {
  var msg = "It does not work like that";
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "nope1", "alert('" + msg + "!')", true);
  //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "nope2", "alert('" + msg + "')", true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way it will work. As the name of the function says, it register the startup script so you are changing it instead of inserting 2. In this way it will do both ^^

```js
if (condition)
{
    if (condition2)
    {
        var message = "It happened !"; 
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "yep1", "alert('"+message+"');", true);
    }
}
else
{
    var msg = "It does not work like that";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "nope1", "alert('"+msg+"!'); alert('" + msg + "');", true);
    //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "nope1", "alert('"+msg+"!')", true);
    //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "nope2", "alert('" + msg + "')", true);
}
```

Comment: So number of startup scripts that can be registered is 1 and the way how to call more than one function is to chain them into one string?
Just a note msg is not declared in the second if statment.
//Yes it works. Thank you very much.